# Eclipse: console window as editor tab

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

SlickEdit has one nice feature, it allows to move the console window to the editor tab so that it appears like a file. Is it also possible in Eclipse?

Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

As @Sandman mentioned, in Eclipse 3.x the views stay separate from the Editor Area.  In Eclipse 4.1 (based on e4 modeled workbench) we've added preliminary support to drag a view into the Editor Area.

See http://download.eclipse.org/e4/sdk/

PW

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. This is because editors are located in the Editor area, and Console view is, well, a view and not an editor.

However, as far as I know, in Eclipse e4 there is no longer any difference between views and editors, so it may be possible to do something like that there.